# How to determine which question belongs where?

Tags: discussion, scope, review

There are few questions which are asked in the main site for which other users ask the poster of the question to post it in stackoverflow, or other stackexchange sites.

Some of these questions are definitely meant for these sites. But there are lot of border questions which cannot be easily determined if they belong in this site or not.

Can a feature be included such that when users specify that feature, the question can be first checked by *certain people to determine whether it belongs to this site or not, before it is answered?

*By certain people I mean, those who have a certain reputation and above.

I am sorry for this question, I just found out that one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031419/how-to-programmatically-read-until-a-certain-character-in-a-file) was migrated to another site from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you request is pretty much already implemented. When you ask a question people having enough reputation to cast a vote feel that it doesn't belong to Unix&Linux, your question is migrated as the result of a decision involving at least five people or a moderator.

If, after having read the FAQ and other questions, you're unsure on whether your question belongs here or not, just post it and if it needs to be migrated, it will be. That's not a problem.

What I mean is that you don't have to feel *bad* because your question has been migrated, nobody will be angry at you for having posted such a question here. :-)

And no, you should not delete your question, it no longer exists on Unix&Linux. It has been migrated to StackOverflow where it received an answer so everything is cool.